# Why does SAS ask me to save my excel file on every run?

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I am using SAS ODS statement to create excel files in a program like so:

```
ods listing close;
ods tagsets.excelxp file='filters.xls' style=statistical
  options(autofilter='2-7' frozen_headers = '3' index='yes' sheet_name='triangle' embedded_titles='yes');
  title "Accumulated Triangle Table";

proc print data=TriangleSist; run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
ods listing;
```

However, when I run this program, SAS asks me whether I want to save the excel file each time I run it with a pop-up dialog.  How can I get it to stop doing that?

Comment: Why dont you use path?, like:
ods tagsets.ExcelXP path='output-directory' file='MyWorkbook.xls';
 and here ist a document which mentions it: http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.sas.com%2Fresources%2Fpapers%2Fproceedings12%2F150-2012.pdf&ei=a_iTVeWTI8mdsgHZm4moBw&usg=AFQjCNGnYBw3BFB3Z1FAAY90zy5GQ989JQ&sig2=rKtOD0L8GcTMSq7lyE3UVQ&bvm=bv.96952980,d.bGg

Comment: I've never had SAS prompt me for a path in that situation.  Why not simply say file="c:\whaeer\filters.xls"?

Comment: I tried both `path="directory" file="filters.xls` and `file="directory\filters.xls"`

With both options, Excel or SAS asks me if I want to open the Excel file or if I want to save it. Maybe it is an option in Excel or SAS.

One good news, at least when I click the "save" button, it brings me directly to my target directory now.

Comment: Hm, are you changing the application header somewhere before your ods statement?

Comment: Which header do you mean? You mean the library name?  As general, I think my variables are consistent through my code.

Comment: I've modified the question to more clearly include that information - the comment above makes it much more clear.  This has nothing to do with the "path" itself, as the answer showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup would be showing in case of using PC SAS. This is happening due to certain Results setting setup on the PC SAS. Try going to **Tools -> Options->Preferences -> Results tab**.
In the Result tab under Results options section uncheck "view results as they are generated". This should stop the popup for open/save/cancel to show up and the excel file would save on the folder location mentioned in the file= options.